# Does JavaScript `arguments` contain `this`?

Tags: javascript, arguments

I'm trying to understand JavaScript's `arguments` implicit variable in functions. Some tutorials delete the 0th element of it and say that it contains `this` but some other tutorials don't delete the 0th element. I'm very confused.

I wrote this code example and it shows that `arguments` doesn't contain `this`:

```
function aaa () {
    console.log(arguments[0])
}

aaa(1,2,3);
```

Is it possible that sometimes `arguments` contains `this`? I wonder why some tutorials slice away the 0th element before using `arguments`.

Comment: This could simply be a case of "stop @#!&*$% learning programming from 'tutorials'"

Comment: Provide a link to that tutorial. They may be doing this for other reasons. `arguments` does not contain `this`.

Comment: `arguments[0]` holds the value of the first formal parameter.

Comment: maybe you mean you've seen `var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);` ? ...which is common way to create array from arguments

Comment: There's no relationship there. They probably just mean that they want to call some other function and use the first argument as the `this` value of that function. `some_fun.apply(first_arg, rest_of_the_args)`

Comment: A link to that tutorial would be helpful for context.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Arguments is an array* of the original arguments passed into the function, and doesn't directly have anything to do with the "this" variable.

That said, different tutorials probably try to explain how function references work, etc, using the scope (scope => "this" variable) of the function. This could easily involve passing an array and shifting off the first argument.

Consider this simple snippet:

```
var sample = function(a,b,c){ 
    console.log(arguments, this); 
}; 
sample(1,2,3);
```

Outputs:

> [1, 2, 3], window

As we know by now, "this" is a special variable that has to do with the scope of the function. There are [plenty of articles](http://javascriptissexy.com/understand-javascripts-this-with-clarity-and-master-it/) describing what it does/how it works, but in this context specifically, you've probably seen things used in a manner with .call or .apply:

```
sample.call(sample, 1, 2, 3)
```

or

```
sample.apply(sample, [1,2,3])
```

Those snippets both do the same thing - they convert the "this" scope of the function from the window object (since "sample" was declared as a global function) to the "sample" function itself, and pass the parameters 1, 2 and 3. They output:

> [1, 2, 3], [sample function]

The reason some tutorials will shift off the first argument in this context is that there are often "helper" functions to make it more obvious when scope is changed, and many times those helper functions take, as their first parameter, the scope in which the new function is to be executed. So, they shift off the first parameter, and use that when (essentially) calling apply. A common example is bind(), like so:

```
Function.prototype.bind = function(scope){
    var me = this,
        args = Array.prototype.slice.apply(arguments, [1]);

        return function () {
            var handlerArgs = []; 
            for (i = 0; i < args.length; i++) {
                handlerArgs.push(args[i]);
            }
            for (var i = 0; i < arguments.length; i++) {
                handlerArgs.push(arguments[i]);
            }
            me.apply(scope, handlerArgs);
        };
};
```

Now, you can call:

```
var bound = sample.bind(sample, 1);
bound(2,3);
```

...and get the output:

> [1, 2, 3] [sample function]

You can see we're passing some parameters (the scope and the first parameter) when we bind the function initially, at which point we slice off the first argument ("sample", because that's the "scope" and has to be handled differently than any other arguments), then later, when bound() is invoked, push the 1, as well as 2 and 3, into the final arguments list.

It's a bit confusing at first, but hopefully that helps a little.

*Technically [array-like](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/arguments).

Comment: arguments isn't an array

Comment: OK, fine, it's array-like. For the purposes of this discussion it's close enough :)

Answer (score 4):

most likely  you have a function like   `blah(x)`   In which case you take off the first argument because it is already captured as the variable `x`, and you want the rest of the arguments that have been passed in.

The first argument is not `this`.